# De-Serializing a generic (but Serializable) type

Tags: java, generics, serialization

I'm wondering if it's possible to de-serialize a generic type into an instance of that type. If it is possible, does Java take into account the generic type's custom de-deserialization (if any)?

In my case, I'm trying to implement a List that is backed by a file which contains the serialized form of the elements, and needs to instantiate a generic type from a byte[], e.g.:

```
class FileBackedList<V extends Serializable> implements List<V> {
    // ...

    public V get(int index) {
        byte[] value = readFromFile(index);
        // ???????
        // I'm pretty certain this doesn't work
        return (V)(new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(value)).readObject());
    }

    private byte[] readFromFile(int index) {
        // read bytes at line 'index'
    }
}
```

Is there any way this type of thing could work?

**Edit:** And if it does work, am I definitely going to invoke the correct readObject(ObjectInputStream in) for type V if it has a custom one?

By the way, I don't want to serialize the entire list.

Comment: Just fix the compilation errors (either implement `List` or extend `ArrayList` and also `ByteArrayInputStream` doesn't have a `readObject()` method) and try yourself.

Comment: skaffman: No, as I don't have the file with the serialized form yet. Even if it would work I want to know if the default readObject() will be used or will V's (the generic type) readObject be called if it has defined a custom one (now edited the question to clarify).        BalusC: Corrected those typos now implements List and added the missing parenthesis so OIS.readObject() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't that work (in principle)? I have not tested your code, but when you use that very `FileBackedList<V>` to serialise your objects into the file, then you can correctly deserialise them again and return them using the unsafe type cast `return (V) ...`. The reason for this is as follows:

- Even if V is translated into Serializable by the compiler, your concrete objects are known to the JVM as what they are, e.g. String, Integer, or any other serializable object. So when you serialise them on the ObjectOutputStream, the concrete type is stored.
- When you load the object again from the ObjectInputStream, you will get the same object with the correct type (e.g. String, Integer or whatever). Which is in fact the same as V

Because you hide the implementation of your list from the outside world, the unsafe type cast will work. Examples:

```
FileBackedList<String> list = new FileBackedList<String>();

// This will probably serialise the String "abc" to your file
list.add("abc");

// This will not work. <V> is always String for FileBackedList<String>
list.add(Integer.valueOf(1));

// This will be type-safe. It can only be String because you bind V to String
String abc = list.get(0);
```

So go ahead and do it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Java generic types are only visible during compilation and in bytecode, and some data are also visible with reflection API. But Java Virtual Machine knows nothing about generic types (like eg .net does), so List<String>, List<Object>, or List<Integer> or just List is all the same for JVM. Your 'V' generic type parameter is just 'Serializable' for Java, nothing more, so your code should work. It's called type erasure (.net generics are implemented with different technique called reification).